# CSS How do I make auto width attribute ignore certain fields?

Tags: css, html, width

So I have an application where I display user data, the div containing this data has an auto width attribute so text won't split into multiple lines. But now I have a problem because this div also contains a block of text. which obviously should be longer than one rule. This results in that the div becomes really wide. which I don't want. I am looking for a solution to make CSS ignore this specific block of text. Is there anyone who knows a solution?

This is the containing div

```
#GenerateInfo{
    overflow: scroll;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 76%;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: 65%;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 100;

    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 18px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 18px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
    box-shadow: 6px 18px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.36);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="GenerateInfo" class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Information</h3><strong>name:</strong>
        <br>Name
        <hr> 
        <strong>Email:</strong><br>email@hotmail.nl<hr>
        <strong>message:</strong>
        <br>
        <span class="limit">rem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam u</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

sorry for the Dutch language in images.
this is what it should look like (even if it has a long message):
[image: this is what it should look like (even if it has a long message):]

This is what it looks like:
[image: This is what it looks like:]

Comment: Can you provide the part of interest of your code, maybe some prints so we can help you properly

Comment: sure give me a second

Comment: so it should size when certain text fields get bigger, and not when others do

Comment: The HTML isn't that complicated I'm using Bootstrap 4.0

Comment: I'm still not certain what you're trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate a bit more? Which div becomes really wide? What do you mean by longer than one rule?

Comment: include an image of what is wrong with it and what you want it to look like.

Comment: sure, so the GenerateInfo div should be as wide as the longest field inside, this would result in that no text should wrap to a second rule because it doesn't fit. But this should not happen for the message field (limit class) because this field could be very big. which would result in the GenerateInfo div to be really big. In this case the div should be as wide as the email is.

Comment: So just give GenerateInfo a `width` other than auto then.

Comment: That won't work because it should be responsive based on the given e-mail etc.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to accomplish is that the max-width of the GenerateInput is the same as the width of the biggest element inside except for the message.

Comment: Do you have more html? Where are the values coming from? Do you have other css too?

Comment: The values are coming from a database with php

Comment: There isn't much more CSS that's important